# How to change the virtual joystick Input direction depending on camera rotation so the player moves to its current forward direction?

Tags: unity, movement, unityscript, joystick

I have a scene set up where the player moves and rotates with Virtual Joystick Input. I have button which rotates the camera to the back of my player at that point I want to change the joystick input direction so it moves my player to towards its current forward direction.

> The joystick Scripts:

**1)** script to handle events:

```
public class joystickEvents extends EventSystems.EventTrigger{
  var position:Vector2=Vector2.zero;

  public var joyStickHolder:Transform;
  private var pointerUp:boolean=false;

  function Update(){
    if(position!=Vector3.zero && pointerUp){
       position=Vector3.Lerp(position,Vector3.zero,5*Time.deltaTime);

    }
  }
   public function OnDrag(data:EventSystems.PointerEventData){
      position=data.position-joyStickHolder.position;
   }
   public function OnPointerUp(data:EventSystems.PointerEventData){

     pointerUp=true;

    }
  public function OnPointerDown(data:EventSystems.PointerEventData){
     pointerUp=false;
  }

}
```

**2)** script for joystick movement:

```
   public class joystick extends MonoBehaviour{
    var joystickEvents:joystickEvents;
    var joystickHolder:RectTransform;
          var dir:Vector3;
    private var maxDist:float;
    private var direction:Vector3;
    private var magnitude:float;

     function Start(){
        maxDist = joystickHolder.sizeDelta.x;
        maxDist=maxDist/2.5;
     }

     function OnGUI () {

        if(joystickEvents.position.magnitude>(maxDist)) 
              magnitude=maxDist;

        else{
          magnitude=joystickEvents.position.magnitude;

        }
        direction=joystickEvents.position.normalized;

      transform.localPosition=direction*magnitude;
        dir=direction*(magnitude/maxDist);
    }
  }
```

The player controller script takes the variable `dir` to move around the world. I think this value must changed somehow to so that move the player moves towards its current forward based on joystick input when camera is rotated.

> Here some part of playerController responsible for player movement:

```
public class charcterController extends MonoBehaviour{
 private var controller  : CharacterController;
 private var moveDirection : Vector3 = Vector3.zero;
 var speed : float = 6.0;
 var joystick:joystick; //reference to the joystick script
  function Start(){
       controller = GetComponent.<CharacterController>();
    }
  function Update() {
        var joyInput:Vector3=joystick.dir; //the dir in joystick script
        dir=Vector3(joyInput.x,0,joyInput.y);
        if (controller.isGrounded) {
        moveDirection = dir;

        moveDirection *= speed;
        controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
         rotate();
      }
  function rotate(){
      if(dir!=Vector3.zero)
          transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(dir);
      }
 }
```

[image: image of player movement]

Answer (score 1):

You want to transform `dir` according to the camera:

```
dir = cam.TransformDirection(dir);
```

This treats `dir` as if it was a direction relative to the camera, and returns what the direction would be if global. You can read more about it on the [Unity Scripting API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformDirection.html).

Also, I notice the camera has a slight downward angle. Getting it relative to the camera would mean trying to move slightly down all the time. You could fix that by setting the y on the transformed `dir` to zero. Then, if you want to preserve magnitude, `newDir.normalized * oldDir.magnitude`. Alsogether, it might look something like this:

```
var cam : Transform;
function Update() {
    ...
    dir = cam.TransformDirection(dir);
    moveDirection = dir;
    moveDirection.y = 0;
    moveDirection = moveDirection.normalized * dir.magnitude;
    ...
}
```